# Prove a miscellaneous result regarding Vector Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $U$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$, and if $u$ and $v$ are elements of $V$, but one or both not in $U$, can $u+v$ be in U? Can $cu$ be in $U$ for some nonzero scalar $c$ if $u$ is not in $U$?

I tried coming up with counter-examples but failed to come up with a proper one. I have no Idea how to prove this using Mathematical Statements. (Question from Gareth Williams)
P.S : I couldn't come up with a proper title since the question isn't something that could be put to small words.

Answer (score 2):

1) Let us consider two cases:

- When only one belongs to the subspace, say $u \in U$, then the sum can't belong to $U$. Else, we'd have $(u + v) - u = v \in U$ (because $-u \in U$ and $(u+v) \in U$)
- When both belong to the subspace, yes, it can happen. Consider for example $V = \mathbb{R}^3$ and $U$ the plane $z=0$. Consider vectors $(x,y,z)$ and $(x,y,-z)$ for $z \not =0$ and for all $x,y$. They won't belong to $U$ but their sum will.

2) No, it can't. If $cv \in U$ then you have $\frac{1}{c} cv = v \in U$

Comment: I think there is a sub-case to 1, when one-but-not-both is not in $U$.

Comment: You're right. I'll edit this. I read too fast and thought OP was only asking for both.

Comment: Thank you for the examples, but is there anyway to mathematically prove them?

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want to prove, exactly? Consider that first part of 1 is a proof using vector subspaces properties. The same holds for 2. The second part of 1, instead, is just an example to show that it may happen.